# Where can I look to find what kind of oil I should use for my car

Tags: oil

Right now I want to change the oil in my 2002 Kia Sedona but I have several cars and I'm never quite sure what kind of oil to use in them.

What I'm really looking for is a link to a site that I can go to in general when changing my oil or a friends.

Others have asked this question before and the answers are always read the owners manual.  Unfortunately I don't have one so this isn't an option for me this time.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select the right oil for my car?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/how-do-i-select-the-right-oil-for-my-car)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.kia.ca/pages/owner/ownersmanual.aspx or other links from your friendly manufacturer website or DDG/Google?

Section 7-40 in [one](http://www.kia.ca/content/Owners/OwnersManual/2002_Sedona_Owners_Manual_EN.pdf) says

```
Engine Oil    API Service SD or above, SAE 5W-30
```

You can also get feedback from brand user and fan forums/sites/lists/clubs etc. But RTFM is the correct first answer to the question.

Comment: Excellent link.  I was hoping for a general website for more than just Kias but this is a great first start.

Answer (score 3):

Just like others have already told you, you really just need to locate an owners manual for the car.  Should be able to get one from the dealer for a minimal cost.  Or, see if there's a Haynes or Chiltons manual available, they have that information too.

Answer (score 1):

There are some oil brand name companies that have a [vehicle selector page](http://www.mobiloil.com/USA-English/MotorOil/Car_Care/Vehicle_Chooser/VehicleChooser.aspx) and they will tell you what they recommend. But again, the owner's manual is the best place to look for the correct viscosity.