# Euro Long-Life Synthetic in a Hyundai?

Tags: oil, hyundai, oil-change, accent

### **tl;dr: Does it make any worthwhile difference to put European oil in a Korean car (Hyundai), or would any other synthetic work just as well?**

### My Vehicle Info

2008 Hyundai Accent, 
GLS 4-Door,
SEDAN 4-DR,
1.6L L4 DOHC 16V,
odo. 155,000 miles (Canadian car, so reads 250,000 km)

---

I've been taking my Hyundai for regular oil changes at a local shop that does the following ***every*** time:

- Terraclean Engine Oil Service Kit - 2 Part

  - I don't know which kit exactly, but probably one of the ones listed here: http://www.terraclean.net/services/engine-services/
- Oil filter
- Total - Engine Oil 5w30 Ineo Long Life Ultra Premium Euro-Syn
- I think it's this product (or else another in the same product line): http://www.total-canada.ca/en/automotive-catalogue/catalog.canada.en/ineo-longlife-5w-30-en.html
- Because of this premium oil change service, the mechanic says that I only need an oil change half as often: every 6,000 miles (10,000 km) instead of every 3,000 (5,000).

**Does it make any worthwhile difference to put a European oil in a Korean car? Would any other synthetic work just as well?**

### Related questions:

- Is Terraclean necessary at all? This article seems to say no:

> If your vehicle is healthy and shows no signs of excessive oil consumption, this treatment is unnecessary. Use quality fuel, change oil and other fluids as recommended and your engine will last hundreds of thousands of kilometres without assistance from such products. https://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-drive/culture/commuting/is-my-garage-taking-me-to-the-cleaners/article14440034/

- If both quit the Terraclean and buy a different synthetic, doing the oil change myself, can I still do it only every 6,000 miles (10,000 km)?

  - e.g. Castrol EDGE Extended Performance: https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/castrol-edge-extended-performance-syntheticengine-oil-4-4-l-0289256p.html#srp

Comment: FWIW The Hyundai USA service schedules say 3000m oil change for "severe" driving conditions and 7500 for "normal". The Hyundai international website gives a 10,000m oil "normal" change interval and 6,500 in countries with average summer temperatures over 40C (e.g. the Middle East) or driving at speeds over 100mph, neither of which seems likely in Canada. So take your pick!

Comment: You may find this interesting, as well as the other questions linked to...  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/7461/10976